# Cypress allure plugin doesn't generate full report when running "Run x integration specs" in headed mode

Tags: cypress, allure

I'm using [cypress-allure-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin) in order to generate allure reports for cypress tests.

When I try to run all the specs in headed mode automatically I don't get a full report as every other test except the last has a `"skipped"` status in the report despite that not being the case when I watch the tests being executed.

This issue seems to be exclusive to using the `"Run x integrations specs"` since running them one by one manually in headed mode doesn't produce this issue and neither does running them in headless mode.

Has anybody encountered a similar issue?

EDIT: I think I found the issue. Sometimes the tests reload wipping current test results and only results that were generated afterwards are used in the report.